# Multi-threaded software design

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization, locking, singleton

Question, Let's say I had Thread A and Thread B and both of these needed access to a singleton object and it's properties.

Currently the singleton looks as follows.

```
public class Singleton{

        #region fields
        private static Singleton singletonObject;
        private double value1= 0;
        private double value2= 0;
        private double value3= 0;
        private double value4= 0;
        private object locker = null;
        #endregion

        // private constructor. This will avoid creating object using new keyword
        private Singleton() {
            locker = new object();
        }

        // public method which will be called
        public void GetName() {
            Console.WriteLine("singleton Object");
        }
        public static Singleton Instance() {
            // this object will be used with lock, so that it will be always one thread which will be executing the code
            object instanceLocker = new object();
            // put a lock on myObject. We won't be able to use singleTonObject becuase it will be null. lock is to make the object thread safe.
            // lock can't be worked with null objects.
            lock (instanceLocker) {
                // check whether the instance was there. If it's not there, then create an instance.
                if (singletonObject == null) {
                    singletonObject = new Singleton();

                }
            }
            return singletonObject;
        }

        public double Value1 { get { lock (locker) { return value1; } } set { lock (locker) { value1= value; } } }
        public double Value2 { get { lock (locker) { return value2; } } set { lock (locker) { value2= value; } } }
        public double Value3 { get { lock (locker) { return value3; } } set { lock (locker) { value3= value; } } }
        public double Value4 { get { lock (locker) { return value4; } } set { lock (locker) { value4= value; } } }


    }
```

My question. Rather than having thread safe properties, is there a better approach?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently your code is completely broken. You're creating a new object to lock on during *every call*. No other thread will ever know about it, so it's completely pointless.

Don't bother trying to fix it in clever ways. Just initialize it in the static variable initializer:

```
private static Singleton singletonObject = new Singleton();
```

Nice and simple.

For more information about implementing the singleton pattern in C# (including using `Lazy<T>` in .NET 4), see [my article on the topic](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx).

Comment: +1 I just came to the same conclusion. Oh, and DoubleDunk, there isn't really any better general solution. There might be something better for your specific situation, but then we would need to know more about what you use this class for.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. So, basically initialize the locker object after the static singleton initialization and not within the constructor?

Comment: Jon, thank you very much for your answer. I implemented the 2nd solution in your article. However, I am liking the 4th solution. I can't thank you enough and shall bookmark your article. Thanks again.

Comment: @DoubleDunk: Do you really *need* to initialize really lazily? The fourth approach is the one I'd normally use. As for `locker` - the brokenness was due to `instanceLocker`, not `locker`.

Comment: Yes I know. I got rid of instanceLocker and stuck with locker. I like the 4th approach and will implement it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the fact that you're creating a new object to lock on for every call, there is another fundamental problem: even if you do have the same object, you're still not really protecting anything.

Somewhere along the line you initialize `Value1` to 9:

```
Singleton.Instance().Value1 = 9;
```

Now let's say you have two threads executing this code:

```
public void Foo()
{
    Singleton.Instance().Value1++;

    if(Singleton.Instance().Value1==10.0)
    {
         Singleton.Instance().Value2 = 20.0;
    }
    else
    {
         Singleton.Instance().Value3 = 30.0;
    }
}
```

Thread A calls `Value1++` and incrementing value1 to 10.0
Thread B calls `Value1++` and now the value1 is 11.0
Thread A checks if the value value1 is 10.0 -> returns false!
Thread A sets `Value3` to 30
Thread B sets `Value3` to 30 also.

This is just a very simple example where locking the properties will not protect you since the external code does nothing to guarantee the order in which things are being read or written. There could be a number of other orders in which Thread A and Thread B are executed which will result in completely different outcomes.

This behavior may be OK, since you could have let the user of the `Singleton` class take the responsibility for ensuring the correct operation outside your class, but it's generally something you should be aware of. Simply locking the properties will not eliminate the read/write contention.

Comment: Very good point and something I will keep an eye for during my development. Thank you much.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using .NET 4.0? Instead of locking, you can use ConCurrent collections for thread safe activity.

Comment: I am using 3.5, but there isn't anything stopping me from using 4.0. Thank you for your input, I will look into it.

Comment: I'm just not seeing the link between a *singleton* and a *collection* here.

Comment: @BrianGideon The Singleton has 4 doubles.  Rather than storing them all separately, you could have a single concurrent collection that simply has 4 (double) values in it.

Comment: @Servy: Yeah...indeed. I guess I didn't consider that. It still seems like a stretch though.